# Adding PNG/SVG symbols on the map on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, style

I am trying to add all symbols (cafe, hospital, school, and etc...) on my map on GeoServer.

For the test I added this code (to see the cafe symbol):

```
name: Test
title: Test
feature-styles:
- name: name
  rules:
  - filter: ${type = 'cafe'}
  symbolizers:
  - point:
      symbols:
      - external:
          url: file:/Downloads/symbols/Cafe.p.16.png   
          format: image/png
```

But I got empty screen, even there weren't buildings, lacks... Only white screen.

Then, I tried:

```
name: Test
title: Test
feature-styles:
- name: name
  rules:
  - filter: ${type = 'cafe'}
  symbolizers:
  - point:
      symbols:
      - external:
          url: file:/Downloads/geoserver-2.11.1/resources/120px-Cafe-16.svg
          format: image/svg
```

But result is the same.

Polygon, line, road styles are SLD files, but point is YSLD.
If it's important, the order of styles is:

1. Polygon
2. Roads
3. Line
4. Point

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your url should be `file:///Downloads/symbols/Cafe.p.16.png`, a look in the log file will show what GeoServer is trying and failing (?) to load.

As an aid to finding out what is wrong (it could be the selection filter) SLD (and the derived styling languages) allow you to specify a number of symbols so that if the first one doesn't work the second will be drawn and so on down the list. So try either adding a second symbol (e.g. a square) or just replacing the svg symbol with a square to make sure that the svg is really the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, i didn't do it with iant answer (as, I am new one: I was trying to change the file path on the GeoServer and on my PC, and checking for the any errors).

But I find my way through SLD:

```
    <Rule>
                 <ogc:Filter>
                      <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>amenity</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>restaurant</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                 </ogc:Filter>
                 <MaxScaleDenominator>8900</MaxScaleDenominator>
                 <PointSymbolizer>    
                   <Graphic>
                     <ExternalGraphic>
                        <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/5/55/Restaurant-16.svg" />
                       <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                     </ExternalGraphic>
                     <Size>20</Size>
                   </Graphic>
                </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

(Link wiki.openstreetmap.org is for testing only)

Maybe it can help to someone.